# Huge gap after creating table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Ive created a table with a plugin app i use a pagelines theme for my wordpress website...

http://www.studymychild.co.uk/adelina-mustafa-timetable-2013

however after creating a custom table the page has a huge gap then the table at the bototm for example

GAP 
GAP
GAP
GAP
GAP

TABLE 1 2 3 4 5

The coding i used is (by the way im trying to create a student time table)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{monday900am1030am}</td>
      <td>{tuesday900am1030am}</td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
      <td>{monday1030am1045am}</td>
      <td>{tuesday1030am1045am}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spaceUnder">
      <td>{monday1045am1230pm}</td>
      <td>{tuesday1045am1230pm}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's nothing here with which to troubleshoot. Either post the rendered HTML or show us a demo.

Comment: http://www.studymychild.co.uk/adelina-mustafa-timetable-2013 this is the page im having trouble with

Comment: Hmm... how is this [tag:database-design]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is your problem:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

If you're using line breaks to adjust your page layout, you're doing it wrong. :-)

Edit in response to your comment... obviously the code is coming from somewhere. Look for whitespace in a WYSIWYG editor.

If you absolutely can't find it, this CSS will hide paragraphs and line breaks inside the table's parent div element. It's rather a hack, though, and will likely cause problems down the road.

```
.entry_content br, .entry_content p {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: hi there thank you for your reply, however the code ive given is the only code im using i havent used <br> :( im confused